# How to refresh FlatList on callback of modal

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm successfully generating a FlatList from Realm with no issues. However, when I close my modal screen after adding a new record, the data doesn't refresh automatically (however it does after a "Pull to Refresh"). Can someone help me understand what needs to be called in the "HOW_TO_REFRESH" placeholder?

FlatList Generation:

```
export default class Accounts extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      accountid: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      balance: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })),

    onDeleteItem: PropTypes.func,
    onRefreshItems: PropTypes.func,
    onSelectItem: PropTypes.func,
    refreshing: PropTypes.bool

  };

  static defaultProps = {
    onDeleteItem: (item) => {
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.delete(realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Account', item.accountid));
      })
    },
    onRefreshItems: () => { console.log('Refresh accounts'); },
    onSelectItem: (item) => { console.log('onSelectItem ', item); },
    refreshing: false
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
      activeRow: null
    });

  }

  renderItem(info, activeRow) {
    return (
        <AccountListItem item={info.item} onPress={() => this.props.onSelectItem(info.item)} />
    );
  }

  render() {

    const listSettings = {
      data: realm.objects('Account'),
      extraData: this.state.activeRow,
      keyExtractor: (item, index) => item.accountid,
      onRefresh: this.props.onRefreshItems,
      refreshing: this.props.refreshing,
      renderItem: (info) => this.renderItem(info, this.state.activeRow)
    };

    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Left></Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Accounts</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button transparent
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddAccount', {name: 'Accounts', onGoBack: () => HOW_TO_REFRESH})} >
              <Icon name="ios-add" />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
        <Container>
          <FlatList {...listSettings} />
        </Container>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Called in my modal to navigate back:

```
navigation.goBack();
navigation.state.params.onGoBack();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your own method

```
goBack= () => {
    //do code for refresh flatlist
}
```

mention it when you are navigating

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AddAccount', {name: 'Accounts', onGoBack: () => this.goBack})
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I understand how to call the refresh code, I just don’t know what the refresh code is. What would go in the “// do code for refresh flatlist” section?

Comment: ok, in that case just use `extraData={this.state}` instead of `extraData: this.state.activeRow`. And then in your goBack method call `this.setState({})`